# Sql statistical riddle

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and trying to get some statistical data in certain format because it is loaded into graphs which shouldn't be changed.

Graph acceps date, type and sum. Type in my case in domain name and sum is how much was sold per day for this site.

Now I have two DB tables, `Users` and `Sales`. `Users` have `userID` and `registrationSite` columns. `Sales` got `saleID`, `userID` and `sum`. This is the query I get all details for my stats with one problem.

I should get "0" value in select even if there was no sale for this domain on this date to make graph to work. Is there a way to do it?

```
select 
    sum(s.sum) sum,u.registrationSite,
    dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, s.date), 0) date 
from Users u
right join Sales s on u.userid=s.userid
where 
    s.date > dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
group by 
    registrationSite,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,s.date),0)
order by 
    dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, s.date), 0)
```

Comment: You need an outer join onto a dates table (or a numbers table which you use as a dates table) to fill in the missing dates.

Comment: @Martin, what do you mean by that? Do you mean to create dates table and outer join to it on which "on clause"?

Comment: I believe Martin means changing your `right join` to a `full outer join`.

Comment: @Lieven, it didn't set to null sum of sites where is no single sale at the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is this output you are looking for or you can modify ti get exactly what you want.

`cteDates` builds a list of dates from today and one month back. The cross join against `distinct RegistrationSite` makes sure that you get one row for each combination of date and site. `left outer join` to sales gets the sum for each date/site row.

```
;with cteDates as
(
  select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as [Date]
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, -1, [Date]) as [Date]
  from cteDates
  where [Date] > dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
)
select
  sum(coalesce(s.[Sum], 0)) as [Sum],
  r.RegistrationSite,
  cd.[Date]
from cteDates as cd
  cross join (select distinct RegistrationSite
              from Users) as r
  left outer join 
      (select [Date], [sum], RegistrationSite
       from Sales
         inner join Users
           on Sales.UserID = Users.UserID) as s
   on cd.[Date] = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, s.[Date]), 0) and
      r.RegistrationSite = s.RegistrationSite
group by r.RegistrationSite, cd.[Date]
order by cd.[Date]
```

Result

```
0           site 1           2011-03-12 00:00:00.000
0           site 2           2011-03-12 00:00:00.000
0           site 1           2011-03-13 00:00:00.000
0           site 2           2011-03-13 00:00:00.000
60          site 1           2011-03-14 00:00:00.000
50          site 2           2011-03-14 00:00:00.000
0           site 1           2011-03-15 00:00:00.000
40          site 2           2011-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks it works, i was trying to avoid this mess with calendar but seems this is the only option so far...